# Questions on member function design for the class Complex

Tags: c++, oop, class

In the book *The C++ Programming Language*, the author claims that, for the following class design,

```
class complex{
   double re, im; 
public: 
   double real( ) const { return re;}
   double imag( ) const { return im;}

};
```

> Given real() and imag(), we can define all kinds of useful operators without granting them direct access to the representation of complex.

How to understand this statement? Where do we need direct access and where do we need indirect access?

The author also gives the following example.

```
inline bool operator==(complex a, complex b)
{ 
   return a.real( )==b.real() && a.imag () ==b.imag( );
}
```

How is this given example related to the author's statement given in the above.

Comment: That's a bad example (which suggests that it may also be a bad book) - you should never test floating point values for equality using `==`.

Comment: @Paul - huh ? How to test if two `double`-s are equal ?

Comment: @Kiril: you need to test whether the absolute difference is smaller than epsilon, e.g. `fabs(a.real - b.real) < EPSILON`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: @Paul - right, thanks, I usually do it like this(`fabs`), but not always and just wandered if there's a "smarter" way (: Thanks (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `operator==` is a free function, which is not even `friend` of the class, so it cannot acess the private members of the class, but it has access to public member functions of `complex`, so it can implement `operator==` with the help of public member functions. That is what meant by the author. This is also a good demonstration of [**data encapsulation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) by the author!

By the way, the implementation can be further improved by defining as,

```
inline bool operator==(const complex & a,const complex & b) //note difference!
{ 
   return a.real( )==b.real() && a.imag () ==b.imag( );
}
```

Please notice the parameters: now, they're defined as *reference* so as to **avoid** unnecessary copy!

Answer (score 1):

what the author is talking about here is known as "encapsulation". The new function that defines "==" defines the logic for comparing two objects of your new type (complex) without having to know what the internals of a complex number actually look like.

Your question is really vague, so i think what you want to do is learn a little more about "object oriented programming" and "encapsulation". A google search on these terms should help.

in fact, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It is related in that you don't access `re` and `im` directly, but, instead access them through access functions `real()` and `imag()`.

If the function were to be written like this:

```
return a.re==b.re && a.im==b.im;
```

then it had to be a friend function (need access to private members).

Answer (score 0):

The author is trying to illustrate the advantage of not exposing the actual implementation details of the class `complex`.  At any time you can change the actual underlying implementation, without needing any other code to change, so long as those 2 methods always do what the user expects them to.

Answer (score 0):

This means, that you don't provide access to the real members of `Complex`, as `re` and `im` are private and the getters (accessors) return a copy of the value. That's called encapsulation.

The example shows how to compare 2 `Complex` objects, without touching the private data members. (otherwise, if you make the `re` and `im` public, anybody can change them anytime, which destroys one of the main goals of OOP - as I said, encapsulation).

Answer (score 0):

The `operator==` checks whether two complex numbers are equal through their `real`/`imag` interface, without touching the `re` and `im` members directly.

This means that

1. a function receiving a `complex &` cannot change the members because they are effectively `const` (only reachable through `const` accessors), and
2. you can later change the `complex` class to store numbers in [polar form](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form) instead, without breaking anything but the `real` and `imag` members.

This is called "encapsulation" or "data hiding".

Comment: Well, you actually can change a complex& parameter, by creating a new complex value and assign that. :-)

Comment: @Bo: yes. I meant that you can't change the members *individually*.